# How can I allow the user to click "through" javafx stage for an "overlay" style application?

Tags: javafx, overlay, desktop-application

I'm creating an application to help people with visual impairments. If you imagine something similar to flux, I want to overlay a filtered version of the screen to the user but still allow them to interact with everything else as usual.

Therefore, there are two things I need to work out:

1. I need some way to display the output of the filtered screen across the whole screen while still allowing the user to interact with what is underneath.
2. I need some way of capturing the screen input as if the filter wasn't there.

Are either of these things possible?

Comment: The "click through" aspect will probably give you trouble. It can be done on Windows, at least in my experience, but I've seen questions on this site which show it doesn't work on macOS; not sure about Linux. I don't know if this problem is JavaFX specific or if macOS simply doesn't allow "click through" functionality.

Comment: That said, the way to accomplish "click through" behavior is to make at least part of the window entirely transparent. You do that by configuring the `Stage` to use the `StageStyle.TRANSPARENT` style, setting the fill of the `Scene` to `Color.TRANSPARENT`, and then setting the backgrounds of all appropriate `Region`s to `Color.TRANSPARENT`.

Comment: A part of the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678009/javafx-click-through-overlaying-stackpane) but it only looks at one aspect which is having JavaFX ignore mouse events

Comment: @Slaw I am not aware of such a problem on the Mac. Can you be a little bit more specific or provide some pointer please? What exactly doesn't work on Macs?

Comment: @mipa Simply that the JavaFX window consumes the mouse events, regardless of transparency, thus preventing you from interacting with whatever is "behind" the JavaFX window. This could have been fixed in a newer version of JavaFX or macOS, but I remember seeing at least 2 questions (that were never satisfactorily answered) around 2-3 years ago showing issues with "click through" and each time the OP was using macOS; however, the exact same code would work on my Windows machine. If you don't experience issues then it may have been specific to those people's particular setup/environment.

Comment: @Slaw Ahh, I think I misunderstood your comment and the question of the OP. You are talking about windows and not about layers inside a single application.