# Problem with hbox not letting radio buttons work

Tags: javafx

My project is about rolling dice, but right now, I'm just making the framework. My radio buttons aren't working. It doesn't click like the other buttons. The buttons are in a hbox. I think the problem might be with the last hbox. I deleted it, and the radio buttons work. I don't want to delete the hbox, so I would appreciate it if someone can help me. I am new to JavaFx, so my code might not be the best. Thanks, here is my code

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    
    Label title = new Label("Welcome to 4-Dice Draw Poker");
    title.setLayoutX(125); title.setLayoutY(20);
    
    Label name = new Label("Enter Name");
    name.setLayoutX(90); name.setLayoutY(60);
    
    TextField tfName = new TextField();
    tfName.setLayoutX(170);tfName.setLayoutY(60);
    
    Button button = new Button("Click for 1st Roll");
    button.setLayoutX(160); button.setLayoutY(130);
    
    Label dice = new Label("Dice");
    
    Label roll1 = new Label("2");
    Label roll2 = new Label("2");
    Label roll3 = new Label("4");
    Label roll4 = new Label("6");
    Label outcome = new Label("Pair");
    
    HBox hbox = new HBox(dice);
    hbox.getChildren().addAll(roll1, roll2, roll3, roll4, outcome);
    hbox.setSpacing(23);
    hbox.setPadding(new Insets(200, 0, 0, 50));
    
    Label draw = new Label("Draw");
    draw.setLayoutX(49); draw.setLayoutY(235);
    
    RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton();
    RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton();
    RadioButton rb3 = new RadioButton();
    RadioButton rb4 = new RadioButton();
    
    HBox hbox2 = new HBox(rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4);
    hbox2.setSpacing(7);
    hbox2.setPadding(new Insets(235, 0, 0, 93));
    hbox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    
    Button button2 = new Button("Click for 2nd Roll");
    button2.setLayoutX(160); button2.setLayoutY(280);
    
    Label dice2 = new Label("Dice");
    
    Label roll1a = new Label("2");
    Label roll2a = new Label("2");
    Label roll3a = new Label("4");
    Label roll4a = new Label("6");
    Label outcome2 = new Label("Pair");
    
    HBox hbox3 = new HBox(dice2);
    hbox3.getChildren().addAll(roll1a, roll2a, roll3a, roll4a, outcome2);
    hbox3.setSpacing(23);
    hbox3.setPadding(new Insets(335, 0, 0, 50));
    
    Button button3 = new Button("Play Again");
    button3.setLayoutX(173); button3.setLayoutY(390);
    
    Pane pane = new Pane(title); 
    pane.getChildren().addAll(name, tfName, button, hbox, draw, hbox2, button2, hbox3, button3);
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 430, 480);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Comment: Try downloading scene builder from gluon and prototyping your GUI using that tool, even if you don’t end up using fxml.  Try to let layout panes do more of the work rather than hard coding sizing and positions.

Comment: The padding is part of the hbox, it should not be used for positioning, it is used for managed layout calculations to separate nodes.  If you decide to keep the absolute positioning, then remove the padding and use set hbox.relocate(x,y) to position it.

Comment: Also see [pick on bounds setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678009/javafx-click-through-overlaying-stackpane), though you should try not to layer panes if you don’t need to, so be careful not to do stuff just to mask other short comings.

Comment: A Pane uses a [painter’s algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm) for rendering content and processing clicks,  so when a hbox with padding is placed over another control and picking is on bounds or the hbox has a background color, it will intercept clicks that would otherwise reach potential event targets underneath it.